# how to fill an element with an image to fully use the space available?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

What I want to do is enlarge the image enough so fully occupy the space available in an element block like the following image: (the black box is the element box and grey supposed to b image.)
[image: Please follow the link below to view the image]

In my code here the image just CONTAINS the element box. That is not what I want. I want it to enlarge a bit to fully occupy the space of an element. How do I do it? I have already seen similar questions and their answers and they were not satisfying my need. Please help with this.

I have this code

```css
.category-box{
    width:320px;
    height: 320px;
}
.category-box-1{
    background-image: url('https://unsplash.com/photos/pvICOT96zY8');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!-- A CONTAINER HAVE TOTAL OF 3 BOX-->
        <div class="fw-bold d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap" id="categories">

          <!-- BOX-1 OR SUB-CONTAINER-1-->
          <div class="category-box category-box-1 bg-dark m-2 p-4 ">
            <h2 class="h2-responsive">Women's</h2>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-dark" href="#">
              Show Now
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.svg" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>
            
          <!-- BOX-2 OR SUB-CONTAINER-2 -->
          <div class="category-box category-box-2 bg-dark m-2 p-4">
            <h2 class="h2-responsive"> Men's</h2>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-light" href="#">
              Show Now
              <img src="images/arrow_forward.svg" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>
            
          <!-- BOX-3 OR SUB-CONTAINER-3-->
          <div class="category-box bg-dark m-2 p-4">
            <h2 class="h2-responsive">Kids</h2>
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-light shop-now-btn" href="#">
              Show Now
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.svg" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: instead of using contain, you can use `cover` which will maintain the image aspect ratio but crop the image. alternativly you can use `fill` where the image will not be cropped but stretched: [MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: if you talk about background-size: [MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Resizing_background_images)

Comment: @tacoshy thank you for helping. Using 'cover' solved the image problem. I was having the same problem for hero image. but the "Shop Now" button is still an issue

Comment: @otaku what do you want to with shop now button? Please describe more what you get now. and What do you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

i think this code solve your problem.

this is html and css.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  background-color:coral;
  height:100px;
}
span{
  flex:0 0 60%;
}
img{
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Content</span>
  <img  src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: **down-voted for following reasons:** Answer missing a sufficient explaination. Answers with code only can be considered low-quality. They hard hard to understand and as such also hard to reproduce. Also answer missing simplicity. flexbox is the wrong approach when you could simply use `object-fit`

Comment: also please take the [tour] first (befor you ask or answer a question). Then also read: [answer]